# Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, winforms, dispose

Vejo que existem muitos objetos com método `Dispose()`, li a respeito que serve para liberar recursos. Mas isto não acontece automaticamente?

Se eu estiver criando uma classe que dentro dela eu utilize um formulário e alguns controles durante a execução da classe. Como, por exemplo:

```
public class A
{
   private Form Frm {get; set;}
   private Label Lbl {get;set;}

   public A()
   {
      Frm = new Form();
      Lbl = new Label();
      Frm.Controls.Add(Lbl);
   }

   public void Show()
   {
      Frm.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

Esta classe é apenas para exemplo da situação. Devo me preocupar em usar a interface `IDisposable`? Quando devo usar o `Dispose()`, quando o objeto é destruído ele não libera para mim automaticamente todos os recursos?

Comment: Você deve usar dispose quando o objeto diz na sua documentação que ele não é tratado pelo garbage collector (e portanto deve ser disposed). Um exemplo é a classe `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Comment: Compreendo, mas a resposta parece meio vaga pra mim. Neste exemplo que dei que possuo um Form e uma Label, não precisaria de método dispose? Caso fosse uma classe que cuida de banco de dados, deveria utilizar um dispose que chama o dispose da conexão?

Comment: Os recursos de um objeto são sim liberados automaticamente pelo GC depois que o objeto não é mais necessário. Mas os recursos automaticamente liberados são os chamados **recursos gerenciados** (ou *managed resources*). Já os **recursos não gerenciados** (ou *unmanaged resources*), como acesso ao disco, à rede, *handles*, conexões com o banco de dados... não são liberados automaticamente e necessitam de um cuidado extra, que pode passar pela implementação da interface *IDisposable*. Um dica é: se o objeto que você consome é *disposable*, procure garantir a chamada ao seu método *Dispose*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Parece haver alguma confusão de conceitos.

Liberação de recursos é diferente de liberação de memória. O *garbage collector* libera a memória quando ele puder e achar necessário. Ele não libera recursos.

## O que é liberar recursos?

Quando você possui acesso a alguma "coisa" que tem um vínculo com a aplicação em determinado momento este vínculo precisa ser finalizado de alguma forma. Um exemplo típico é o arquivo em um disco. Para ter acesso a ele você o abre criando assim um vínculo com a aplicação. Em algum momento este arquivo precisa ser fechado desfazendo este vínculo. Isto precisa ser feito o mais rápido possível. Não pode aguardar o *garbage collector* entrar em ação. Você não tem controle quando ele fará a liberação da memória, *tracings GC* não são determinísticos.

Há linguagens, normalmente sem GC ou com *reference counting*, que a liberação de memória e liberação do recurso pode ser feita de forma sincronizada.

Todas as classes que precisam desta liberação devem implementar a interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ou seja, precisa criar uma implementação do método `Dispose()` que encerrará a vinculação do recurso com a aplicação. Por isso é comum que a implementação chame o método `Close()`.

Alguém poderia pensar, chame o `Close()` logo. Ok, é possível fazer isto. Mas você precisa de uma maneira de fazer isto de forma padronizada. Precisa criar um *padrão de projeto*.

Quando o programa cria uma instância de uma classe que implementa o `Dispose()`, ele deve garantir que o método `Dispose()` seja chamado de uma forma ou de outra.

O mais comum é usar o *statement* [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145858/101). Desta forma você cria um escopo, então quando a instância sair de escopo, o método será chamado "automaticamente" sem que você se preocupe. Mas você tem que se preocupar em criar a instância do jeito certo, tem que criar como `using`. Algumas [ferramentas de análise estática](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) de programas podem ajudar lhe avisando que você esqueceu de criar a instância com o `using`. Não fique sem o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

## Porque o `Form` não precisa disso?

Claro que você pode chamar o `Close()` por conta própria. O que importa é o `Close()` ser chamado. Neste caso o `Close()` chamará o `Dispose()` se for necessário.

Um encerramento implícito de um formulário poderá chamar o `Close()` para você. Mas isto depende da forma como ele foi criado.

O `ShowDialog()` não chama o `Close()` por conta própria. Então você deve chamar. O `ShowDialog()` fecha o `Form` de um jeito diferente (de forma modal), não providenciando a desvinculação necessária. Quando ele termina de executar é como se ele tivesse apenas sido escondido. Então você poderia chamar:

```
public void Show() {
    using (var frm = new Form()) {
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Em versões mais recentes do C# pode fazer assim:

```
public void Show() {
    using var frm = new Form());
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Dispose.cs).

Se isto não for possível, você vai ter que garantir, de outra forma que o `frm` seja liberado quando não for mais necessário.

Por outro lado se você chamar `form1.Show()` ou `Application.Run(new Form1())`, o `Close()`, e portanto o `Dispose()` será chamado por você. Quando você não quer mais mostrar o formulário você deve chamar o `Hide()`, caso contrário o `Form` será destruído. [Veja a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_Close?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Note que essa destruição é referente ao recurso e não necessariamente da memória alocada para ele. A memória só será desalocada pelo GC.

## Criando uma classe `IDisposable`

Por outro lado se a sua preocupação é implementar uma `IDisposable` na sua nova classe, isto depende se você está usando um recurso nela. Normalmente um recurso externo a aplicação, algo que precisa ser desvinculado. Normalmente isto é feito em um nível de abstração mais baixo, onde você efetivamente vai manipular o recurso externo de forma mais concreta.

O fato de você estar usando recursos dentro da sua classe não obriga a implementação da `IDisposable`. Se você puder garantir a liberação de todos os recursos dentro de sua própria classe, então ela não precisa ter o `Dispose()` dela.

Mas se isto não puder ser garantido, então você precisa de um `Dispose()` implementado nela e provavelmente dentro dele todos os `Dispose()` das instâncias que precisam ser liberadas deverão ser chamados.

## E se eu esquecer de chamar o `Dispose()`?

Qualquer tentativa de acesso ao recurso pode conflitar (ser negado, por exemplo). Mas isto só ocorrerá até a primeira coleta de lixo. Se não há mais nenhuma referência para a instância, o GC vai chamar o `Finalize()` e este irá chamar o `Dispose()`, se necessário. Então a liberação de recursos ocorrerá em algum momento, mesmo que seja no encerramento da aplicação.

Isto é válido se não houver um término catastrófico. Claro que se o .NET não conseguir concluir corretamente, nada disto vai acontecer. Mas aí o sistema operacional provavelmente vai resolver a situação, destruindo todos os vínculos ainda existentes para uma aplicação que não existe mais, bem como a memória alocada para ela. Se o término ocorrer por *boot* da máquina nem é preciso se preocupar com nada, tudo estará liberado por razões óbvias.

Comment: Aproveitando o tópico, a sua boa explicação. Caso minha classe necessite de **Dispose**, devo chamá-la no destrutor?

Comment: É uma das possibilidades. Mas deve-se tomar cuidado. Eu mesmo não sei bem todas as situações que um destrutor deve ser usado e quando deve ser evitado ou preferido o uso do `Finalize()`. Me parece que este é um caso típico para seu uso, pelo menos a documentação mostra assim. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx. Veja mais no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628752/why-call-disposefalse-in-the-destructor E ainda...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339063/what-is-the-difference-between-using-idisposable-vs-a-destructor-in-c e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456213/destructor-vs-idisposable e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface. Não é que precisa chamar, mas se não chamar, pode ter vazamento do recurso. Esta é a última oportunidade que a aplicação tem para fazer a liberação de um recurso que provavelmente já deveria ter sido liberado. Depois disto, só o SO poderá fazer a liberação no fim da aplicação. Então podemos dizer que é obrigatório.

Comment: Isso está errado: *"Se não há mais nenhuma referência para a instância, o GC vai chamar o Finalize() e este irá chamar o Dispose(), se necessário."* Na verdade, a implementação padrão do *finalize* (a implementação fornecida por *Objetc*) não faz nada e sequer é chamada pelo GC se não tiver sido implementada em uma classe filha. A rigor, para garantir que os recursos não gerenciados sejam liberados caso o consumidor esqueça de chamar o *dispose*, é necessário implementar explicitamente o *finalize* (no caso do C#, o *destructor*) para que ele invoque o *dispose*.

Comment: Pelo que eu tenho visto, a maioria das implementações de *dispose* em C# são incompletas pois se baseiam em equívocos como este. Isso só não causa maiores problemas porque na prática geralmente usamos classes .Net para acessar recursos não gerenciados, e estas por sua vez fazem uma implementação completa do padrão *disposable*, de modo que quando caputaradas pelo GC acabam fazendo as liberações necessárias mesmo que o programador tenha esquecido de chamar o *dispose* ou tenha feito uma implementação ruim do seu próprio *dispose*.

Answer (score 8):

Você deve utilizar o `Dispose` para liberar recursos antes do garbage collector passar para limpar a referência a seu objeto.

Isso deve ser feito, porque há cenários onde o garbage collector pode demorar muito a passar para limpar seu objeto (ou em casos muito particulares, pode nem passar para limpá-lo, deixando-o vivo até o término da aplicação). Nesse meio tempo, os recursos (como imagens, conexões de banco de dados etc.) permanecem alocados.

Contudo, se você souber que não irá mais utilizar o objeto, deve-se chamar o método `Dispose` para liberar manualmente os recursos. Isso se torna especialmente importante em cenários como aplicações Web de grande porte que utilizam conexões com banco de dados (o SGBD pode limitar a quantidade de conexões simultâneas, logo, quanto antes você liberar uma conexão, mais rapidamente outra conexão poderá ser feita em seguida).

Dê uma olhada nessas outras perguntas aqui, juntamente com as respostas, que podem te fornecer mais informações e exemplos:

[Conceitos de Alocação e Liberação de Mémória em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/conceitos-de-aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-libera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-m%C3%A9m%C3%B3ria-em-c/)

[O que significa '~' na frente do construtor de uma classe C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9078/o-que-significa-na-frente-do-construtor-de-uma-classe-c/)