# Erro: Nem todos os caminhos de código retornam um valor

Tags: c#, .net, return, controle-de-fluxo

Segue o erro:

> "Conta.LoginCliente(string, string)":nem todos os caminhos de código
> retornam um valor

```
    class Conta
    {
        #region atributos
        public String nomeCliente { get; set; }
        public String numAgencia { get; set; }
        public String numConta { get; set; }
        public Boolean contaExiste { get; set; }
        public Decimal saldoCC { get; set; }
        public Decimal saldoPoupanca { get; set; }
        
        #endregion

    #region metodos
    
    public  Conta()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Conta não existe");
    }
   
    public Conta(String znome, String zAgencia, String zConta, Decimal zsaldoCC, Decimal zsaldoPP)
    {
        nomeCliente = znome;
        numAgencia = zAgencia;
        numConta = zConta;
        saldoPoupanca = 0.0m;
        zsaldoCC = 0.0M;
        contaExiste = true;
    }

    public Conta LoginCliente( String Agencia, String Conta)
    {
        DAO.SQL conexao = new DAO.SQL();
        conexao.AbrirConexao();
        Conta conta = conexao.ConsultarCliente(Agencia, Conta);
        conexao.FecharConexao();
        if(conta != null)
        {
            return conta;
        }
```

Comment: Gente o erro que estou recebendo tá vindo do LoginCliente

Comment: O que você deseja retornar se a conta for nula? O `ConsultarCliente()` recebe a conta como argumento. E retorna conta também. Pode ser outra conta? Pode ser nula? Este código tem várias coisas esquisitas.

Answer (score 8):

O erro acontece porque você não está retornando nada explicitamente.
Para consertar, recomendo que crie uma variável para fazer o `return`:

```
public Conta LoginCliente( String Agencia, String Conta)
{
    Conta retorno = null;
    DAO.SQL conexao = new DAO.SQL();
    conexao.AbrirConexao();
    Conta conta = conexao.ConsultarCliente(Agencia, Conta);
    conexao.FecharConexao();
    if(conta != null)
    {
        retorno = conta;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Ou faça o retorno explicito do que deseja retornar e retorne conta caso a condição seja verdadeira:

```
public Conta LoginCliente( String Agencia, String Conta)
{
    DAO.SQL conexao = new DAO.SQL();
    conexao.AbrirConexao();
    Conta conta = conexao.ConsultarCliente(Agencia, Conta);
    conexao.FecharConexao();
    return conta != null ? conta : null;
}
```

Usei o `null` só para ilustrar melhor a solução, até porque não teria motivo retornar `null`, sendo que o valor de conta já vai ser `null` nessas ocasiões. Mas caso queira retornar nulo mesmo, só não fazer o `if`:

```
public Conta LoginCliente( String Agencia, String Conta)
{
    DAO.SQL conexao = new DAO.SQL();
    conexao.AbrirConexao();
    Conta conta = conexao.ConsultarCliente(Agencia, Conta);
    conexao.FecharConexao();
    return conta;
}
```

Comment: Pode transformar o if/ternário num `return` direto que tem o mesmo efeito para o código ilustrado

Comment: Sim, como foi escrito no final da resposta, usei o `null` só para ilustrar melhor a solução, mas acredito que o mais apropriado não seria retornar `null`.

Comment: Não me expliquei corretamente, eu quis dizer fazer `return conta;` diretamente.

Comment: @Isac Sim, eu entendi, você quem não me entendeu kkk. Editei minha resposta, de qualquer maneira. Para ficar mais facil de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um código melhorado dentro dos padrões do C#.

Também comentei que precisa implantar o [padrão *disposable*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101) na classe de conexão para garantir que a conexão seja fechada mesmo se uma exceção for lançada. Não foi muito fã desses gerenciadores de conexões, mas o pior é que alguém fez uma errada, divulgou e todo mundo copia errado sem entender o que está acontecendo aí.

```
public Conta LoginCliente(string agencia, string conta) {
    DAO.SQL conexao = new DAO.SQL();
    conexao.AbrirConexao(); //esta classe deveria adotar o padrão Disposable
    Conta cliente = conexao.ConsultarCliente(agencia, conta);
    conexao.FecharConexao(); //se der exceção isto nunca será executado
    return cliente;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnPath.cs).

O motivo do erro é que o `return` está em um trecho de código condicional, então se entrar no `if` tem um `return`, mas se não entrar não tem, ele precisa retornar uma `Conta` aconteça o que acontecer no código, a não ser que role uma exceção.

Comment: ps. `conta` é um parâmetro e logo abaixo está declarando um objeto do tipo `Conta` de mesmo nome.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis esse código todo não faz sentido, eu respondi mais por causa disto. Eu reescreveria tudo, mas isso não dá, então pelo menos resolve alguns problemas dele assim. Dei uma melhorada, com sua observação. Esses nomes me confundiram. Obrigado.