# Erro ao depurar por null em conexão

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, testes-de-unidade, configurationmanager

Quero documentar um teste unitário mas estou recebendo erro:

> System.Exception: 'Erro ao fechar conexão com banco de dados: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'

O meu caso de teste foi assim codificado:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using DAL.Model;
using DAL.Persistence;

namespace GErenciamentoTarefas_TesteUnitario
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        TarefaDAO td = new TarefaDAO();
        int retorno1 = 0;
        int retorno2 = 0;
        int retorno3 = 0;

        [TestMethod]
        public void testeIncluirTarefa()
        {
            Tarefa tarefa1 = new Tarefa();
            tarefa1.DataEntrega = "19/11/2018";
            tarefa1.Nome = "Nome em Teste";
            tarefa1.Responsavel = "Responsavel em Teste1";
            tarefa1.Tipo = "1";

            Tarefa tarefa2 = new Tarefa();
            tarefa2.DataEntrega = "22/11/2018";
            tarefa2.Nome = "Nome em Teste";
            tarefa2.Responsavel = "Responsavel em Teste2";
            tarefa2.Tipo = "2";

            Tarefa tarefa3 = new Tarefa();
            tarefa3.DataEntrega = "25/11/2018";
            tarefa3.Nome = "Nome em Teste";
            tarefa3.Responsavel = "Responsavel em Teste3";
            tarefa3.Tipo = "3";

            retorno1 = td.Gravar(tarefa1);
            retorno2 = td.Gravar(tarefa2);
            retorno3 = td.Gravar(tarefa3);

            Assert.AreEqual(0, retorno1);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, retorno2);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, retorno3);
        }

    }
}
```

A minha classe de conexão está assim codificada

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DAL.Persistence
{
    public class ConexaoAccess
    {

        protected OleDbConnection Con;
        protected OleDbCommand Cmd;
        protected OleDbDataAdapter Da;

        protected void AbrirConexao()
        {
            try
            {
                //Busca a string de conexão com o banco no arquivo Web.config
                Con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoBanco"].ConnectionString);
                Con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao abrir conexão com banco de dados: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        protected void FecharConexao()
        {
            try
            {
                Con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoBanco"].ConnectionString);
                Con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao fechar conexão com banco de dados: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Tentei corrigir alterando a posição do objeto `OleDbConnection`:

```
public class ConexaoAccess
{

protected OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoBanco"].ConnectionString);
protected OleDbCommand Cmd;
protected OleDbDataAdapter Da;
```

mas não tive êxito.

O depurador aponta que o erro é sempre ao fechar a conexão:

[image: Mostrando o erro]

Qual a  solução?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários erros aí. Testar dessa forma e nada é quase a mesma coisa. Isso não testa de fato, não cria situação que mereça testes.

[Capturar exceção para lançar outra exceção não faz o menor sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101), mas principalmente [capturar `Exception` é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101), você captura erros que nm está querendo tratar.

Abrir uma conexão para depois fechá-la na linha seguinte sem fazer nada faz menos sentido ainda.

Na verdade [o certo não é ter que fechar a conexão explicitamente assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101), ou seja tem erros arquiteturais na sua aplicação. É possível até separar a abertura da conexão mas é bem mais complexo que isso e só recomendável para quem sabe criar classes com funcionalidades completas, tratamento adequado de exceções

E dá pra ver ter outros problemas menores no seu código. A impressão que dá é que não está entendendo o que este código executa, e isso é até mais um motivo para não se preocupar com testes formais assim, eles são válidos quando há entendimento.

Eu poderia tentar arrumar o erro, mas manteria todos os outros erros que são mais graves. A melhor ajuda que posso dar é desistir dessa arquitetura ou estudar profundamente como ele deve ser feita para fazer de maneira adequada. Seria complicado dar uma resposta com uma solução. E eu até preferia nem ter essa classe. Ela traz problemas e nenhuma vantagem.