# Objeto COM separado do RCW adjacente

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, oledb

Neste try-catch ocorre a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código:

```
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            cmdQry.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ItensEmbaOrdem WHERE idOrdem=?";

            cmdQry.Parameters.Clear();
            cmdQry.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(cbCodigo.Text)));

            OleDbDataReader RD = cmdQry.ExecuteReader();
            while(RD.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(RD["nomeEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["unEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["qtEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["loteEmba"].ToString());

                lvEmba.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\nCódigo PRO05X137", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
```

Este erro já aconteceu comigo, porém não me lembro de como resolvi, além do mais pesquisei sobre este objeto COM e seu RCW e não encontrei nada. Gostaria de saber a causa do erro e o que são esses dois objetos. Grato.

P.S: o erro só ocorre no ponto `OleDbDataReader RD = cmdQry.ExecuteReader();` e APENAS neste ponto do código.

**EDIT**

O código completo:

```
private void cbCodigo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
               + Application.StartupPath + @"\dbProjetoLagune1.mdb";

        OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);

        OleDbCommand cmdQry = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
```

CÓDIGO NÃO NECESSÁRIO AQUI NO MEIO

```
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            cmdQry.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ItensEmbaOrdem WHERE idOrdem=?";

            cmdQry.Parameters.Clear();
            cmdQry.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(cbCodigo.Text)));

            OleDbDataReader RD = cmdQry.ExecuteReader();
            while(RD.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(RD["nomeEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["unEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["qtEmba"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(RD["loteEmba"].ToString());

                lvEmba.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\nCódigo PRO05X137", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Final do código onde está o erro.

Comment: Onde e como o objeto `cmdQry` é criado? Você aparentemente abriu a conexão com a base usando o objeto `dbConnection`, mas em nenhum momento está passando essa conexão para o objeto de query, `cmdQry`. Acho que estão faltando algumas partes do código para conseguir entender melhor o que acontece.

Comment: Questão editada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema:

Simplesmente precisava fechar o `OleDbDataReader` que estava em outra parte do código com o método `Close()`.

Agradeço àqueles que investiram tempo na questão.

Answer (score 1):

Você criou e abriu sua conexão, porém na hora de criar o `OleDbCommand` você não está associando-o a sua conexão aberta, ou seja, esse comando se refere a qual conexão? Fiz um trecho de código para você ver a alteração que deve ser feita. Adicionei `using` para garantir que o `Dispose` seja chamado no final da utilização dos recursos.

```
using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ItensEmbaOrdem WHERE idOrdem = @idOrdem";

        command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
        {
            new OleDbParameter("@idOrdem",  Convert.ToInt32(cbCodigo.Text))
        });

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(RD["nomeEmba"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(RD["unEmba"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(RD["qtEmba"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(RD["loteEmba"].ToString());

            lvEmba.Items.Add(item);
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Editei a questão onde mostro a associação, por favor dê uma olhada.

Comment: O que o `Dispose()` faz?

Comment: `Dispose` é utilizado para liberar recursos da sua aplicação, vou deixar um link de uma resposta a essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22284/devo-sempre-utilizar-dispose