# Dispose() - Liberação de Recurso ou Liberação de Memória?

Tags: c#

Após ver o tópico "[Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22284/devo-sempre-utilizar-dispose)", ainda sim tive algumas dúvidas e gostaria de saber mais a respeito.

Não é segredo pra ninguém que é ideal usar a instrução Using para objetos [*IDisposable*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2), como descrito a seguir pela própria documentação da Microsoft.

> A instrução using garante que *Dispose* seja chamado, mesmo que ocorra uma exceção dentro do bloco *using*. Você pode obter o mesmo resultado colocando o objeto dentro de um bloco *try* e então chamando *Dispose* em um bloco *finally*.

Dúvida 1: Sabendo disso então, há alguma diferença de performance no tempo de compilação já que tudo será transformado em *try/catch*? Qual seria o ideal?

Dúvida 2 (**Primordial**): Qual seria a melhor prática para a liberação tanto de memória quanto de recurso? Devo setar a variavel = null mesmo estando dentro do bloco *using* para garantir os 2?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com o seguinte trecho: "_Porém na prática sabemos que pode ser um pouco diferente, uma vez em performance outra para evitar Code Smells._"?

Comment: Posso ter me expressado mal quanto ao trecho do texto.

Comment: Gostaria de frisar que eu estava lendo o código do Dispose Pattern antes de ser removido diante chuva de negativação. Ao autor, que não sei o nome, peço que coloque um comentário com o link.

Comment: Difícilmente falta dizer alguma coisa mais que já não foi dito em todas essas perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=dispose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiramente, `Dispose` **não faz "liberação de memória"**. O método serve para finalizar recursos utilizados.

Por exemplo: um arquivo que foi aberto para edição ou uma conexão à rede.

De forma sucinta, quando um programa lê/escreve no disco, faz uma conexão à rede, entre outras operações, é necessário usar recursos do sistema operacional fazendo chamadas de sistema. Portanto, ao terminar de utilizar estes recursos, eles precisam ser fechados/finalizados e é isto que o método `Dispose` faz — ou ao menos deveria fazer, porque sempre vai depender da implementação.

Liberação de memória é algo que não tem nada a ver com isso, quando você cria uma variável, está alocando um espaço na memória e quando esta variável não precisa mais ser utilizada, este espaço pode ser liberado e dar lugar para outro dado. Em casos normais, você não precisa se preocupar em fazer gerenciamento de memória porque numa aplicação .NET o Garbage Collector faz isto automaticamente.

> Sabendo disso então, há alguma diferença de performance no tempo de compilação já que tudo será transformado em try/catch? Qual seria o ideal?

Pode ser que tenha, acho que nem tem como medir de forma eficaz. Mas com certeza não é algo que você deveria se preocupar.

Se tem diferença deve ser algo ínfimo. E convenhamos, comprometer a legibilidade (ou até mesmo a garantia da chamada do método `Dispose()`) por causa de milissegundos (ou micro?) a menos na compilação não me parece uma boa troca.

> Qual seria a melhor prática para a liberação tanto de memória quanto de recurso? Devo setar a variavel = null mesmo estando dentro do bloco using para garantir os 2?

"Melhor" muda de contexto pra contexto, não existe receita de bolo.

Porém, setar a variável pra `null` não vai ter **nenhum efeito**. A única coisa que vai acontecer é que você estará explicitando o fim do uso daquela referência. O que, provavelmente, já vai acontecer em algumas instruções depois de você fazer esta atribuição (por exemplo: fim do método para variáveis locais).

Além de ser inútil, acaba facilitando a introdução de bugs se alguém tentar usar aquela variável depois.

Comment: Poderia me falar um pouco mais sobre a liberação de memória e liberação de recurso que ficou um pouco desentendido ao meu ponto de vista em relação ao uso do Dispose()?

Comment: @VictorLaio Posso, mas o que você quer saber, especificamente?

Comment: Uma explicação breve de cada um deles e em qual deles o Dispose() afeta diretamente ?

Comment: @VictorLaio Só pra ver se eu entendi: você quer saber a diferença entre liberação de recurso e de memória?

Comment: Sim, e se o Dispose() faz a liberação da memória, ou liberação de recurso, ou até mesmo ambos em termos simples.

Comment: @VictorLaio A primeira frase da minha resposta diz isso.

Comment: @VictorLaio Ficou mais claro?

Comment: Sim, obrigado!!